# slider same size as navigation in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation, genesis

i would like the slideshow to have the width as the navigation menu and respond to different devices as the navigation width would.

Heres a link to the website in question http://test.amplifyevents.uk

Comment: please be more specific, link provided does not work.

Comment: please do not use external links to your site for explaning your problem.

Comment: GibboK Updated the link, thanks for pointing that out. basically would like the slideshow to be the same width as the navigation on many devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the width of `rev_slider_1_1_wrapper` to 100%? Your slider will be lining up with Home, not with the complete left of the nav-bar, but that can probably be fixed with a margin.

```
#rev_slider_1_1_wrapper { width: 100% }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work how i would like it. it make the slider width fullscreen instead. could i link with width with navigation somehow.  thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, it looks full screen on smaller browsers, because you work with a framework that makes the page's content change dependent on the width of the browser. So if you want the `rev_slider_1_1_wrapper` to be the same width, you should look at the different widths your menu gets, depending on the browser width (`@media`).

Comment: Found the width of the navigation in browser size. updated the revolution slider widths but instead of the slider going to the minimum width it uses the width on the previous @media

Comment: Maybe you should make some new @media-queries purely for the slider. That's a bit difficult for me to try, as I don't have access to your CSS and all. Good luck!

Comment: Worked a treat, coded the @media-queries and add couple of lines to function.php and worked fine.